# Problem with horizontal divider in Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have the following code:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-5 divide-x divide-gray-700 text-center">
  <div>Col</div>
  <div>Col</div>
  <div>Col</div>
  <div>Col</div>
  <div>Col</div>
</div>

<div class="grid grid-cols-5 gap-4">
  <div class="h-20 border bg-gray-300"></div>
  <div class="h-20 border bg-gray-300"></div>
  <div class="h-20 border bg-gray-300"></div>
  <div class="h-20 border bg-gray-300"></div>
  <div class="h-20 border bg-gray-300"></div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/TLsKEicCOa

That generates this:

[image]

How can I make the vertical borders and the boxes align?

Note: I need two grids, I can't just use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't solve the issue, I decided to research it for you. Actually, this issue was a problem and it needed to make a few changes. You can find solutions for this [issue here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/2466). But still I have a short solution for you as follows. If we give a margin to all child elements, there seems to be no problem. As you wish...

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-5 divide-x divide-gray-700 text-center">
  <div>Col</div>
  <div>Col</div>
  <div>Col</div>
  <div>Col</div>
  <div>Col</div>
</div>

<div class="grid grid-cols-5 [&>*]:mx-2">
  <div class="h-20 border bg-gray-300"></div>
  <div class="h-20 border bg-gray-300"></div>
  <div class="h-20 border bg-gray-300"></div>
  <div class="h-20 border bg-gray-300"></div>
  <div class="h-20 border bg-gray-300"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It work!

Thanks, again, for taking the time to investigate this issue. I honestly tried to get to the link you shared, but I couldn't.

The problem is weird right? I get your solution, but I don't understand why my code doesn't  work :P

Comment: As I understand it, the problem is related to the working logic of tailwindcss. The Divide class adds lines to the intersections of each element. The Gap class adds space between the elements and does not distribute it evenly, it adds it to the end of the first child. I hope I was able to explain. I'm also happy to be able to help you, time doesn't matter.